# Evaluate limit as $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$ of $\frac{y^6}{1+x^2+y^2}$ under the constraint $y \geq |x|$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> Evaluate limit as
> $$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} \frac{y^6}{1+x^2+y^2}$$
> under the constraint $y \geq |x|$.

My teacher uses the polar coordinates and the estimation $\sin^6 \theta \geq \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2})^6}$ since $y \geq |x| \implies \theta \in \left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3}{4}\pi\right]$ to conclude that the limit is $\infty$; I've used another approach, can someone tell me if this is correct?

My approach is: since $y \geq |x| \geq 0$ it follows that $y^2 \geq |x|^2=x^2$, so $1+2y^2 \geq 1+y^2+x^2$ and hence $\frac{1}{1+y^2+x^2} \geq \frac{1}{1+2y^2} \implies \frac{y^6}{1+x^2+y^2} \geq \frac{y^6}{1+2y^2}$. So
$$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} \frac{y^6}{1+x^2+y^2} \geq \lim_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} \frac{y^6}{1+2y^2}$$

Now the last quantity is independent of $x$, but I'm not sure if I can evaluate that as $y\to\infty$ since the limit is $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$ and not just $y \to \infty$. Another question: why the limit is $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$? Shouldn't it be $\|(x,y)\| \to \infty$ and so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to \infty$? Are those two equivalent? Thanks.

Comment: We have $\vert x \vert \leq y$ hence: $ 2y^2 \geq x^2 + y^2 \to \infty$.

Comment: Seems OK to me, missing the $x$, and with $y>0$ then $x^2+y^2\to\infty\implies y\to+\infty.$ Moreover, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to\infty$ and $x^2+y^2\to\infty$ are equivalent